# Combination of two conditions: scroll_pos and screen.width

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scroll_pos = 1;         
    $(document).scroll(function() { 
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_pos < 5) && (screen.width > 480) {               
            $(".jumbotron").slideDown("slow");
            $(".container").css("background-color", "transparent");
            $(".topmenu").css("opacity", "0.5");     
        } else {
            $(".jumbotron").slideUp("slow" );
            $(".container").css("background-color", "#6c5147");
            $(".topmenu").css("opacity", "1.0");
          } 
    });
});
```

I need to achieve that script will not work if the screen is smaller than 480px. If I delete `&& (screen.width > 480)` the script works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the advice, it's my first day with jQuery

Comment: Syntax error correct your if condition and try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `if` condition syntax - you need to wrap all conditions in one set of brackets. Try this:

```
if (scroll_pos < 5 && screen.width > 480) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.